# AutoCAD 2015 cloud of 22k points

Tags: autocad, cad

i have cad file with almost 22k points and i need make circles with the same diameter (30mm) around all of of them, but making it manually will took so long.is there some better way? Some autocad addon od macro? Thanks for any help

Comment: In the old days, Autocad had its own script language call Autolisp. Don't know if still in use in new versions. You can search that

Answer (score 0):

If the points are standard point entities, it wouldn't be too difficult to create a selection set of all points in the file and then add a sphere/circle/block entity at each point. AutoLisp or .Net would handle this very easily.

Comment: They are all selectable but how could i add block entity to all of them with lisp? Or can it be added manually after selected all points?

Comment: Without coding something specifically for you, check out this link: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-map-3d-general/lisp-routine-to-insert-blocks-at-point-locations/td-p/627958